# How do I redirect if a PDF is requested from a given directory with .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a bunch of PDFS in: /uploads/dashboard/

What I'd like to do is, if a PDF is requested from this directory, redirect to a script which checks if the user's current session allows them to access the PDF. If the user is allowed, the script serves the PDF.

Here's where I am:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}/dashboard \.(pdf)$ [NC]   # If filename ends with .pdf and is in the 'dashboard' directory
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dl/$1 [L,R]              # Redirect the user to the auth script
```

However, I keep getting a 404 error with the current code.

This is a Zend Framework application with PHP 5.3 Below are the full contents of my .htaccess:

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On

# Force trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}/dashboard \.(pdf)$ [NC]    # If filename ends with .pdf or .cdr
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dl/$1 [L,R]              # Redirect the user to the other site

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.(jpe?g|gif|png|js|css|swf|flv)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .(jpe?g|gif|png|js|css|swf|flv)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

How might I achieve this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need something like this..

```
RewriteRule ^path/to/pdfs/(.*).pdf       dl/$1.pdf [NC, L]
```